# Trying to access server header set with Vite config is null

Tags: vite, astrojs

I have an Astro application which uses a config which practically reuses almost all Vite config options.
My application has a middleware that reads the headers of the request and adapts the UI based on the presence of a value in the `x-forwarded-host` header.
I am trying to add this value in my vite dev server so I can toggle the UI switch programmatically during development:

```
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
      "x-forwarded-host": "europages",
      "aaa": "bbbb",
    },
  },
```

https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#serverheaders
https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-headers

but when I log the headers from my [middleware](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/middleware/), I don't see these headers:

```js
    export function onRequest(context, next) {
      console.log(context.request.headers.get("x-forwarded-host"))
    }
```

*null*